# datediff() not ignoring time

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using `MYSQL 5.5.47` on Debian and I have this bit in my query:

`AND DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), shouts_stores.date) <= 7`

-- changed it from `AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), shouts_stores.date) <= 7`

The problem?
Datediff, according to everything I've read, is supposed to *ignore the time part*.

I have to get rows of the last 7 days, but I need the timestamps with a time element for "Posted X seconds/minutes/hours/days ago" functionality in PHP.

However, when it comes to just getting the rows, I simply need the posts from up to (and including) 7 days (or 1 week) ago. However, if the posting time is earlier than it is right now, it'll knock it up to 8 days. This causes some confusion. Does anyone have any idea about this?

**edit: example**
This is what the table looks like:

[image]

**tl dr;** I need `DATEDIFF()` to ignore the time part of the `datetime`.

Comment: Can you add an example?

Comment: Yeah, a specific example would be helpful. The documentation is pretty clear that only the date part is taken into consideration, so it would be interesting to see where the problem is

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm not entirely sure where the problem lies. I've used both answers and both worked. Then I returned to my own code, and that also worked. It would seem that the issue was a glitch (?). This would definitely explain why I couldn't find it anywhere else. I have had some other issues post-plesk-update, though. That might have been the cause.

Comment: Perhaps a time zone issue? Even if the time part is ignored, time zone shifts might account for what you saw. Anyway, if it's sorted, all is well...

Comment: Seems unlikely. Even if the timezone in the DB was different (which it isn't), the comparison is done only by the database, so it shouldn't matter. Maybe I just debugged wrong. I'm going to assume the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
... DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(shouts_stores.date)) <= 7
```

Comment: This still takes the time into consideration

Comment: Try SELECT CURRENT_DATE(), DATE(shouts_stores.date) FROM yourtable; to see what it will print.

Comment: My bad, it worked. I wasn't going over the edge and instead looked at how my php code handled it. Both answers fixed it, but yours was first so I'll pick yours :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DATE_ADD(shouts_stores.date,INTERVAL 7 DAY) >= CURRENT_DATE()
```

replace CURRENT_DATE() with NOW() as needed

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I debugged wrongly. - This solution works. Upvote because you weren't the first to answer. Thank you!